# SearchView ui testing android

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, android-espresso, searchview

i have write code to test my SearchView behavior but failed. standard scenario just i want to insert some query into my searcview and then submit

this is my code

```
  onView(withId(R.id.search_match))
        .perform(click())


    onView(
        withId(R.id.search_src_text)
    ).perform(replaceText("Arsenal"), closeSoftKeyboard(), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) //failed here
```

i got error like this

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'replace text(Arsenal)' on view 'with id: com.kuhaku.footballmatchschedule:id/search_src_text'.
```

my xml code

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_search"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_match"
        app:queryHint="Search Match"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What is the text content of `R.id.search_src_text` when the app is loaded?

Comment: nothing, just blank

Comment: It's trying to replace the word "Arsenal" with something, but it can't find that text to replace. Perhaps the box could have that word in it to replace, or the test could be modified

Comment: i was try to use 'typeText("Arsenal)' but still show the same error

Answer (score 0):

you can reach the search text view by using the resources -> getSystem -> getIdentifier

```
Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
    "id", "android")
```

after that you can perform clearText(), then type the text that you want and perform the click on the keycode enter

```
onView(withId(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("search_src_text",
"id", "android"))).perform(clearText(),typeText("enter the text"))
.perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading about that and find a [google example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/ActionBarSearchActivityTest.java) about that's

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(click());  //open the searchView
    
onView(withId(R.id.search_src_text)).perform(typeText("Replace this text"));// the text was input
            
onView(withId(R.id.action_search)).perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));  // starting the object  search
```